# What kind of SQL injections do you know?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'll provide a simple one here:

```
$query = "select id from accounts where email='$_POST[email]' and psw='$_POST[password]'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$con);
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

If the `password` is `1' or '1'='1`,then will do the trick!

What other tips have you known?

Comment: Hrem... Seems like this is about to become a hacking con ;)

Comment: does that thing is not a duplicate, I think this question is asked over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most popuplar example of SQL injection ( from [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Injection - Forms of Vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Forms_of_vulnerability)

Answer (score 0):

[Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) - SQL Injection Examples](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

These are other popular forms of SQL Injection Detection and Testing:

- Union Query SQL Injection Testing
- Blind SQL Injection Testing
- Stored Procedure Injection

[Testing For SQL Injection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OWASP-DV-005)#Union_Query_SQL_Injection_Testing)